# Как сделать сводную ("перевернуть") таблицу?

Tags: python, парсер, csv, pivot

Есть таблица с данными:

```
ID модели | модель | категория характеристики | название характеристики | характеристика
```

Пример :

```
1 | Phillips 100 | size  | length   | 100
1 | Phillips 100 | size  | width    | 200
1 | Phillips 100 | size  | height   | 200
1 | Phillips 100 | screen| diagonal | 25
1 | Phillips 100 | price |          | 100$
2 | Phillips 200 | size  |  width   | 300
2 | Phillips 200 | size  |  height  | 300
3 | Phillips 300 | tech  |  smart tv| 3 generation
```

То есть, количество строк для каждой модели может отличаться, в третьей колонке может быть пустое значение.

Я хочу из этого сделать CSV для импорта в БД, то есть подобной структуры:

```
id| name        | size_length| size_width| size_height|screen_diagonal|price|tech_smart_tv
1 | Phillips 100| 100        | 200       | 200        | 25            | 100$| 3 generation
```

Перепробовал много вариантов, но пока без особых успехов.
Сейчас на этапе создания цикла, который бы парсил нужные значения в пределах `id`, сохранял и переходил к следующему `id`. Но пока всё работает некорректно.

Может быть есть какие-то стандарты решения подобных задач?

Пока я действую по такой логике:

```
f = open('folder/table.csv', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()

#Далее создаю цикл while, для разделения по id
i = 0
while i < int(lines[-1].split(';')[0]):

    #Достаю список элементов с id 1 (и далее по циклу)
    target = [item for item in lines if item.split(';')[0] == str(i+1)]

    for lis in target: 
        #Разбиваю строки по ячейкам
        ttarg = lis.split(';')

        # А вот дальше начинаются проблемы, т.к. не могу корректно вытащить
        # нужные мне значения
        # Пытаюсь подобным образом:
            try:
                n_nn = [item for item in ttarg if ttarg[2].find('ch_cat') 
                != -1 
                and ttarg[3].find('ch_name')!= -1 ]
            except:
                pass
        # Но это работает некорректно, как и опробованные ранее 
         варианты(инкремент while на месте)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", header=None, 
                 names=["id", "name", "attr1", "attr2", "val"])
df = df.assign(col=df.pop("attr1")+"_"+df.pop("attr2").fillna(""))
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace(r"_$", "")
res = (df.pivot_table(index=["id", "name"], columns="col", 
                     values="val", aggfunc="first", fill_value="")
         .reset_index())
res.to_csv("c:/temp/res.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

результат (`c:/temp/res.csv`):

```
id;name;price;screen_diagonal;size_height;size_length;size_width;tech_smart tv
1;Phillips 100;100$;25;200;100;200;
2;Phillips 200;;;300;;300;
3;Phillips 300;;;;;;3 generation
```

Comment: Решение даже превзошло ожидания, огромное спасибо!

Comment: @ptpwork, был рад помочь)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

1. Разбиваем строку по `;` и соединяем поля 3 и 4, таким образом сразу получая названия будущих столбцов типа `size_width`, `size_height` и т.д.
2. Формируем древовидный словарь вида:

   ```
   {
       id : {
                name : {
                           size_width : 100,
                           size_height : 200,
                           ...
                       }
            }
   }
   ```
3. Параллельно запоминаем уникальные заголовки столбцов (`size_width`, `size_height`, ...), они понадобятся для печати.
4. Печатаем словарь, перебирая по очереди айдишники и разворачивая каждый в `csv` строку. Сначала идут поля `id` и `name`, остальные в соответствии с упорядоченным списком заголовков.

---

**Решение**

```
with open("input.txt", 'r') as in_file:
    headers = set()
    nested_dct = {}

    for line in in_file:
        lst = line.rstrip('\n').split(';')

        lst[2] = f"{lst[2]}_{lst[3]}" if lst[3] != '' else lst[2]
        del lst[3]

        i_d = lst[0]    
        name = lst[1]   
        merged_ch_name = lst[2]

        if i_d not in nested_dct: 
            nested_dct[i_d] = {name : {}}

        nested_dct[i_d][name][merged_ch_name] = lst[3]

        headers.add(merged_ch_name)

    headers = sorted(headers)
    print(';'.join(['id', 'name'] + headers))

    for i_d in sorted(nested_dct.keys()):
        # popitem() нужен так как название неизвестно - не можем указать
        # ключ стандартным способом: nested_dct[i_d]['ключ неизвестен'],
        # однако известно, что под айдишником может быть только 1 модель =>
        # вынимаем её. 
        # ключ это имя - идёт в name (например "Phillips 100"),
        # значение - словарь со всеми характеристиками, идёт в rest. 
        name, rest = nested_dct[i_d].popitem()
        row = f"{i_d};{name}" 

        # Перебираем все заголовки, проверяя имеет ли данная модель
        # значение в этом столбце: да - пишем, нет - пропуск.
        for header in headers:
            row += ';'
            if header in rest:
                row += rest[header]
        print(row)
```

**input.txt**

```
1;Phillips 100;size;length;100
1;Phillips 100;size;width;200
1;Phillips 100;size;height;200
1;Phillips 100;screen;diagonal;25
1;Phillips 100;price;;100$
2;Phillips 200;size;width;300
2;Phillips 200;size;height;300
3;Phillips 300;tech;smart tv;3 generation
```

**Output**

```
id;name;price;screen_diagonal;size_height;size_length;size_width;tech_smart tv
1;Phillips 100;100$;25;200;100;200;
2;Phillips 200;;;300;;300;
3;Phillips 300;;;;;;3 generation
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую